# DefaultHttpClient's "connManager" is always null,cant execute http requests

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am building an application in which i prompt users to register. I have a *django-restful* server running at back end , and i m trying to make HTTP post requests to my server on android client with *DefaultHttpClient* class. I get email, username etc from user and at the button's onClick event, i create an *AsnycTask* to execute the request. Here is the code for the activity:

```
registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String userName = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
        String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

        if( userName != null && email != null && password != null) {
            new RegisterEventHandler().execute(userName , email , password);
        }
    }

});

  ....

    class RegisterEventHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {            
        RequestHandler handler = new RequestHandler();
        return handler.register(params[0], params[1], params[2]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if( result ) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            builder.setTitle(R.string.RegisterSuccessfullTitle);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.RegisterSuccessfullMessage);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.OK, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                  

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent redirect = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , SmartMapMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(redirect);
                }

            });

            builder.create().show();
        }
        else {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            builder.setTitle(R.string.RegisterFailedTitle);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.RegisterFailedMessage);
            builder.create().show();
        }
    }       
}
```

The RequestHandler class :

```
public class RequestHandler {

public boolean register(String userName , String email , String password) {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/users/");

    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj.put("username", userName);
        jsonObj.put("email", email);
        jsonObj.put("password", password);      

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString());
        entity.setContentType("application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;

}
}
```

The problem is, *DefaultHttpClient*'s connManager(ClientConnectionManager) is always **null** and on the *execute()* method of the *HttpClient*, it always throws an **IOException**. I tried initializing the *DefaultHttpClient* in my activity , rather than in the AsyncTask's *doInBackground* method , but the result was the same.

Comment: Can we see the stack trace?

Comment: HttpHostConnectException(Throwable).toString() line: 360 
HttpHostConnectException(Throwable).printStackTrace(Appendable, String, StackTraceElement[]) line: 320 
HttpHostConnectException(Throwable).printStackTrace(PrintStream) line: 287 
HttpHostConnectException(Throwable).printStackTrace() line: 235 
RequestHandler.register(String, String, String) line: 44 
RegisterActivity$RegisterEventHandler.doInBackground(String...) line: 59 
RegisterActivity$RegisterEventHandler.doInBackground(Object...) line: 1 
AsyncTask$2.call() line: 287 
FutureTask$Sync.innerRun() line: 305

Comment: It jumps to the  RequestHandler's  catch(IOException e) on debug mode. And trace is this.

Comment: Is your 'django-restful server' on the same Android device? If not you cannot use 127.0.0.1 to connect to.

Comment: You are right, i changed the address and it worked. Thanks :)